# Selenium script runs locally but when I put on the server it doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I made a selenium with Python script that scans followers of Instagram ID and it works perfectly locally. But when I try to run it on the server it doesn't work

I tried both chrome and Firefox driver both work locally, but not on server. The below code is after the user ID is loaded. it works fine till loading user ID.

```py
arrow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="-nal3 "]')
arrow.click()

follower = []

for i in tqdm(range(4), desc='scrolling for follower'):
    driver.save_screenshot('scrollingfollowers.png')
    if driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('h1.m82CD'):
        arrow1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('isgrP')
        arrow1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
        arrow1.click()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        arrow1.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
    else:
        driver.back()
        arrow1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('isgrP')
        arrow1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
        arrow1.click()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        arrow1.send_keys(Keys.END)

html_source = driver.page_source
source_data = html_source.encode('utf-8')
soup = bs(source_data, 'lxml')
for div in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'FPmhX notranslate _0imsa '}):
    if div.text not in follower:
        follower.append(div.text)
```

**Solved**

Thanks for your reply but i figured it out . The problem was that i was using beautiful soup to get all info of followers . It worked locally but when i run it on server it was not collecting that data . 
I used selenium itself to get that data of followers

```
for i in tqdm(range(4),desc='scrolling for follower'):
            time.sleep(1)


            followersList = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[role=\'dialog\'] ul')
            numberOfFollowersInList = len(followersList.find_elements_by_css_selector('li'))
            if int(numberOfFollowersInList) > tenpercent:
                break

            followersList.click()

            actionChain.key_down(Keys.SPACE).perform()


        for user in followersList.find_elements_by_css_selector('li'):
            userLink = user.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
            getuser = userLink.split('/')
            print(getuser[3])
            follower.append(getuser[3])
```

Comment: The *arrow1* variable is defined twice…

Comment: Do you have any trace back or log?